# Using while loop to write a file

Tags: io, while-loop, filewriter

This is my first post so i apologize if it's not the best format. I'm student writing a code to import a document, read a line in the document and then reverse the letters in each word. The new word will be printed into a new file. For example "Jon 123" would be stored and written as "321 noJ". I have gotten the input to work but there is a problem with the writing of the line. The program is only writing the last word that is stored.

The abridged main method code is as follows:

```
    //get first line of text
    line = bw.readLine();

    //while string is not null
    while (line != null)
    {
        System.out.println ("Processing...");   //display message to show work being done

        tokenLine = lineToken(line);    //tokenize string

        //to prevent exception from no token found
        while (tokenLine.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            word = flipWord(tokenLine);     //get next token and reverse letters
            newLine = marginCheck(word);    //store or write line depending on margin

            flushClose(newLine);    //write and flush buffer then close file
        }


        //move to next line in file
        line = bw.readLine();
    }

    flushClose(newLine);    //write and flush buffer then close file

    //output completion message
    System.out.println("The new file has been written.");
```

The relevant methods as follows:

public static StringTokenizer lineToken(String line)
    {
        //local constants

```
    //local variables
    StringTokenizer tokenLine;      //store tokenized line

    /******************* Start lineToken Method ***************/

    tokenLine = new StringTokenizer(line);  //tokenize the current line of text

    return tokenLine;

}//end lineToken
```

public static String flipWord(StringTokenizer tokenLine)
    {
        //local constants

```
    //local variables
    String word;        //store word for manipulation
    String revWord = "";        //store characters as they are flipped

    /******************************* Start flipWord Method******************/
    //store the next token as a string
    word = tokenLine.nextToken();

    //for each character store that character to create a new word
    for (int count = word.length(); count > 0; count--)     
        revWord = revWord + word.charAt(count - 1); //store the new word character by character

    return revWord;     //return the word reversed

}//end flipWord
```

public static String marginCheck(String revWord) throws Exception
    {
        //local constants
        final int MARGIN = 60;  //maximum characters per line

```
    //local variables
    String newLine = "";            //store the new line
    FileWriter fw;      //writes to output file
    BufferedWriter bWriter;     //instantiate buffered writer object
    PrintWriter pw;     //instantiate print writer object
    String outFile  =  "RevWord.text";  //file to write to

    /************* Start marginCheck Method ************/
    //open the output file for writing  
    fw = new FileWriter(outFile);
    bWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    pw = new PrintWriter(bWriter);

    //if the buffered line concatenated with the word is less than the margins
    if (newLine.length() + revWord.length() <= MARGIN)
        newLine = newLine + revWord + " ";      //the buffered line adds the word
    else
        //put an enline character at the end and write the line
        newLine = newLine + "\n";
        pw.println(newLine);

        //use this word as the first word of the next line
        newLine = revWord + " ";
    return newLine;     //return for use with flush
}//end marginCheck
```

public static void flushClose(String inLine) throws Exception
    {
        //local constants

```
    //local variables
    FileWriter fw;      //writes to output file
    BufferedWriter bWriter;     //instantiate buffered writer object
    String outFile  =  "RevWord.text";  //file to write to

    /************ Start flushClose Method *********/
    fw = new FileWriter(outFile);
    bWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);   //initialize writer object

    //write the last line to the output file then flush and close the buffer
    bWriter.write (inLine);
    bWriter.flush();
    bWriter.close();
}//end flushClose
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but my best guess is that every time you write to the file, you are overwriting the file, instead of appending to it.

Try FileWriter(outFile,true);

Answer from: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-append-content-to-file-in-java/

Comment: Perfect. Opened up some other problems but that solves the big one. Thank you.